# Is there any way to assign properties to differentiate values which would otherwise be considered the same? (in C language)

Tags: c, logic, ascii

Let me start by saying that I'm a beginner programmer that knows very basic C
The exact code I'm working on doesn't matter here its just that I've run into a very odd problem (I'm messing around with ASCII graphics)

I want to differentiate between two 'O' characters. I could just use different characters but I want it to look good. I tried using Unicode to differentiate them (since Latin O and Greek Omicron look the same) but it won't work if I send it to someone else (since my output is on command prompt) edit: won't work if I send it to someone since command prompt must be manually configured to allow unicode characters (atleast to my understanding)

I don't know if using structures would work and I want to write this in C and not any other OOP language like python (because I'm practicing C)

So is there any logic I could use to do this?

EDIT: I want to apply different behaviours to both O and there will be multiple O of each type on screen (ik this is what objects do but pls help me with a logic for C)

EDIT 2: Apparently my question is very vague so I'll elaborate

I'm having a 2d array that I'm using as a game screen
I want O to come in from each side (top bottom right left), scroll across the screen and exit from the other side

I already came up with the logic to make it work for a single side but the problem comes in when I want to make it work for all sides

My current logic can't differentiate between an O that has to go left and and O that has to go down

Hence why I want to different between two instances of O

(I haven't posted my code since I just need the logic and want to solve the actual code by myself and also it's probably very inefficient or convuluted etc)

tldr: I  want to differentiate between "O" and "O"

Comment: Differentiate it where? You talk about it "looking good" which implies it is on the screen/terminal. What/where/who does this differentiation need to occur. Giving a precise example of code that illustrates where/how the value is currently set and used would really help.

Comment: @kaylum I want both O to behave differently so ig im talking about differentiating them to apply different logic. Ill make it clearer thx

Comment: Just saying `O` doesn't make it clearer. There are alot of contexts that can have an O. Where does it come from? How is it currently stored? How do you want to use it? Be specific and not just vague abstract "I want to differentiate".

Comment: I do not understand. `t won't work if I send it to someone else (since my output is on command prompt` why? How is "output on command prompt" related to differentiating latin O and greek omicron characters? "Differentiate" -what does it mean exactly? In what way? `apply different behaviours to both O` What behaviors exactly? What does it mean to "apply a behavior" to a character? A character "O" is just a symbol, it has no behavior. `O of each type ` How can a character have type? What do you mean? What types are there? `I want to differentiate between "O" and "O"` What is the context?

Comment: I just wanted logic but I'll talk about my code ig
I'm sorry if it sounds vague but it really is what I want

Comment: Instance of what? You keep saying you don't need to post the code. But you do. Not the full code but a small example that illustrates what you have done and what you want to do. See how here: [mre]. As you should be able to tell, your explanation in words is not being understood by others.

Comment: I'll offer something that *may* help. But can't be sure because can't understand what you are asking. You can use a `struct` to store the character and any other properties you want to associate with that char. For example : `struct instance { char c; int direction; }`

Comment: That reminds me of those letters in certain languages that just look similar to letters in Latin alpabet which are used to fool people in opening URLs that lead to scam server resembling the original website...

Comment: *The exact code I'm working on doesn't matter* That is sooooo ***WRONG***.  The "exact code"  **ALWAYS** matters. You say you're a beginner in C - which means you are unqualified to judge what code matters - if you could, you wouldn't have had to ask this question. Maybe if you add the code you'll get your question reopened and perhaps even answered.  And maybe it'd lose some of its downvotes.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear and I understand that putting the code here would help.
I've gotten an answer i think might work (I am an idiot) thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My current logic can't differentiate between an O that has to go left and and O that has to go down

Your problem is that you don't differentiate *internal representation* and *external presentation*.

You have two distinct objects that move across the screen. They both look like an O character. This doesn't mean your program should store them both as `'O'`, some variation of `'O'` such as the omicron character. The program can *store* e.g. numbers 1 and 2, or any two *different* objects that are convenient to work with, and *display* an O in place of either.

Comment: First off thank you for understanding the question even tho my explanation was lackluster and I didn't provide the code
Second this makes sense to me and i think will work so thank you very much

Comment: Also should I delete this question since it doesn't really help anyone and isn't clear?

Comment: It was clear enough to me, please don't delete.

Comment: I don't mind either way, I'll keep it up. thx again!